# How to get where clause to return nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails 3 application I am using a `before_filter` to make sure that the action can only be used by `permanent` users, i.e. users that are **not** guests:

```
def permanent_user
  @user = User.where('guest != ?', true).find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
end
```

The problem is that I frequently get a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error in the first line when the number of total users in the database is very low.

How can my function be improved to either create a `@user` object or `nil`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
def permanent_user
  redirect_to root_path if current_user.guest?
  @user = current_user
end
```